# Slider Loan Calculator

Tags: jquery, slider, calculator, helper

I've been trying to work this out and have been struggling.

I am looking to create a slider based loan calculator.

I want it to have 2 sliders and 3 numbers generated by the slider positions.
- Slider 1: Loan amount, between £50 - £400 - number box showing value
- Slider 2: Loan length, between 1 - 30 - number box showing value
- number box showing value of ((slider 1 value *120%) / 365) * slider value 2

If you can help I would be so grateful for your input. Massive thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery UI library and try its `change` event:

```
$(".selector").slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
      // do calculations here
   }
});
```